# User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, cocoapods, urbanairship.com

I've got an existing iOS project that I'm maintaining and I needed to upgrade to the latest Urban Airship SDK (5.0.2). The project uses CocoaPods so pulling down the latest version was as simple as `pod 'UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.0.2'` in the `Podfile`, however now when building, I'm getting the compilation errors below:

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.errors */
/%PATH%/Pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/Airship/UI/Default/Inbox/Resources/Shared/UAInboxMessageListCell.xib:3: error: User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0 [6]
/%PATH%/Pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/Airship/UI/Default/Inbox/Resources/Shared/UAInboxMessageListCell.xib:ihY-21-382: error: User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0 [6]
/%PATH%/Pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/Airship/UI/Default/Inbox/Resources/Shared/UAInboxMessageListCell.xib:10: error: User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0 [6]
/%PATH%/Pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/Airship/UI/Default/Inbox/Resources/Shared/UAInboxMessageListCell.xib:20: error: User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0 [6]
/%PATH%/Pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/Airship/UI/Default/Inbox/Resources/Shared/UAInboxMessageListCell.xib:wDW-QM-5ha: error: User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0 [6]
/%PATH%/Pods/UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK/Airship/UI/Default/Inbox/Resources/Shared/UAInboxMessageListCell.xib:9: error: User defined runtime attributes on iOS versions prior to 5.0 [6]
```

It seems to me that this is not an Urban Airship issue, rather the Pods project building against pre-5.0, which is strange because the deployment target is set to 7.0 (on both, the actual project and Pods), running iOS SDK 8.0 (Xcode 6.0.1), so not sure where pre-5.0 would come from.

Any idea/solutions, even partial, would be appreciated.

Comment: Open the UAInboxMessageListCell.xib file and click file inspector, change build for to iOS 5.0.2 or newer, anyway this is my guess.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you!

Comment: Was there ever an explanation on this issue? Mainly, where the pre-5.0 came from in the first place despite deployment target being 7.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the UAInboxMessageListCell.xib file and click file inspector, change `build for` to iOS 5.0.2 or newer